# How to know if an event occurred after or during other events

Tags: r, dplyr, datediff

I am trying to understand if patients at a nursing home who are currently taking a series of drugs had any other drugs between a drugs certain drug of interest and death.The drug of interest is ibuprofen

```
id <- c('1', '1', '1','1','2','2','2')
drug <- c('ibuprofen','aleve','tylenol','claritin', 'ibuprofen','aleve','tums')
start <- c('100','105','50','115','20','-9','30')
death <- c('120','120','120','120','50','50','50')
```

The table of results I am expecting to see shows the drugs that were taken after ibuprofen and before death

```
id <- c('1','1','2')
drug <- c('aleve','claritin','tums')
start <- c('105','115','30)
```

So far this is the code I have, I have only filtered out to show patients with the drug wanted. But I am stuck on how to move forward.

```
y <- df %>%
  filter(drug == "ibuprofen")
```

Comment: We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including small representative datasets in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdataframe)`, if that is not too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner!:

```
dplyr::filter(df, start > start[which(drug == 'ibuprofen')], .by = id)
```

Explanation:

`which()` gets the index where something is true, in this case, the row where the drug is ibuprofen.

We can then use that to find the start value of the ibuprofen row, and then check for each row, if the start is after the ibuprofen start.